# How can I get the background color of a cell from an excel file using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to know if there is a way to get the background color of a cell from an excel file using pandas ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I think a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd would give you more information about how xlrd works with Pandas

Comment: I'd think that `pandas` is not the right tool here. While it can read excel files, its data structures are not made to store meta information on cells.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and Numpy can help you retrieve the cell background colour. Hope this sample code helps you out

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np
workbk = xlrd.open_workbook(file, formatting_info=True)
sheet = workbk.sheet_by_name("sheet_name")
bgcol=np.zeros([sheet.nrows,sheet.ncols])
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        c = sheet.cell(row, col)
        cif = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
        iif = wb.xf_list[cif]
        cbg = iif.background.pattern_colour_index
        bgcol[row,col] = cbg
```