# python get cell color of an excel file opened with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I retrieved an excel file in my python program with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html), and I can read what is written in the cells, but I can't retrieve the background color of the cells, does anyone know if there is a way to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591594/how-can-i-get-the-background-color-of-a-cell-from-an-excel-file-using-pandas

Comment: Looks like this may have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package).